# Download link for SVG (kept as variable)

Tags: javascript, svg

I'm trying to create a link that will allow users to download file with .svg extension. I have SVG code as variable, generated in a fly and after that I want to have HTML code:  Download

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please add some code to show us what you are trying to do and what you have tried. And also read how to create a [mcve] to help get answers to your question.

Answer (score 1):

If you create a fake link with "download" attribute you will be able to download everything you put in its "href", here is a working example that downloads a SVG from a variable:

```
function downloadSVG() {
  let svgData = `<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 96 105">
  <g fill="#97C024" stroke="#97C024" stroke-linejoin="round" stroke-linecap="round">
    <path d="M14,40v24M81,40v24M38,68v24M57,68v24M28,42v31h39v-31z" stroke-width="12"/>
    <path d="M32,5l5,10M64,5l-6,10 " stroke-width="2"/>
  </g>
  <path d="M22,35h51v10h-51zM22,33c0-31,51-31,51,0" fill="#97C024"/>
  <g fill="#FFF">
    <circle cx="36" cy="22" r="2"/>
    <circle cx="59" cy="22" r="2"/>
  </g>
</svg>`;

  /// Create a fake <a> element
  let fakeLink = document.createElement("a");
  /// Add image data as href
  fakeLink.setAttribute('href', 'data:image/svg+xml;base64,' + window.btoa(svgData));
  /// Add download attribute
  fakeLink.setAttribute('download', 'imageName.svg');
  /// Simulate click
  fakeLink.click();

}
```

Usage:

```
<a href="javascript: downloadSVG();">download SVG</a>
```

Demo --> https://jsbin.com/dusanisuwo/3/edit?html,js,output